# Getting an ATL class's instance count

Tags: c++, object, winapi, atl

I apologize if this is a very basic question, but I couldn't find an answer in my ATL book.  Is there an accessible static or global ATL variable that contains the instance count of a given ATL class?  I'm asking because I'd like to do some clean up once I know that the instance count has gone to zero.  Just to clarify, I'm interested in the instance count, not the reference count (which I found is `m_dwRef`).  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such count made as part of ATL itself, the module classes (CAtlExeModuleT and CAtlDllModuleT) have a total usage count but those are shared by all instances. If you want such a count it's easy enough to implement, adding it as part of FinalConstruct/FinalRelease. I suppose you could implement a type derived from CComObject and make the count automatic that way so you wouldn't have to add code to every FinalConstruct/FinalRelease.